# Set key inside order by clause in linq dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I need to set the key in the OrderBy clause using linq , where the key is a property of an object. I only have the property name with me. How can i set the property dynamically.

```
class Obj 
{
    string Level
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
}

List<Obj> objList;

objList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Level); => "here i only have property name."
```

Hope any one can help

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: Reflection to the rescue. Beware it might be slow though.

Comment: yes lc i see ways to get the property name, type but cant found what i need.Might bcoz i am not familiar with reflection.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by **[Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)** and **[Creating Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)** dynamically like

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> enumerable, string sortColumn)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Property(param, sortColumn), param);
    return enumerable.OrderByDescending(mySortExpression);;
 }
```

and for OrderBy

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> enumerable, string sortColumn)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Property(param, sortColumn), param);
    return enumerable.OrderBy(mySortExpression);;
 }
```

and you can combine these two in one like

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> enumerable, string sortColumn, string direction)
{
     var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
     var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Property(param, sortColumn), param);

      IOrderedQueryable<T> iQuery;
      switch(direction)
      {
          case "desc": 
            iQuery = enumerable.OrderByDescending(mySortExpression);
            break;
          case "asc":
          default :
            iQuery = enumerable.OrderBy(mySortExpression);
            break;
      }
      return iQuery;
 }
```

Then you can call it like `objList.OrderBy("Level","asc")` //For Ascending 
`objList.OrderBy("Level","desc")` //For Descending

Hope It will help

Comment: ..thanks for your help ..but its sad that i am working in .net 3.5 and its not working in it.

Comment: @Sunil, updated the answer, all methods will work for .net 3.5

Comment: ..but i am using List.Is the List in 3.5 IQueryable or IEnumerable

Comment: ..i cant find the extension method. I added the method into my project inside a static class. But still not showing in the List class.

Comment: Did you included extension methods class, namespace in the file?

Comment: ..yes its in the same namespace ..:-(

Comment: Yes, It will not work for IEnumerable<T>, but if you have only string type property, then you can try this.  `public static List<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this List<T> enumerable, string sortColumn, string direction) { enumerable.Sort(delegate(T p1, T p2) { return (p2.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn).GetValue(p2, null) as String).CompareTo(p1.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn).GetValue(p1, null) as String); } ); return enumerable; }`